# Problem replacing a String in Java

Tags: java, android, string, android-edittext, bit.ly

I am trying to replace a URL with a shortened URL inside of a String:

```
public void shortenMessage()
    {
        String body = composeEditText.getText().toString();
        String shortenedBody = new String();
        String [] tokens = body.split("\\s");

        // Attempt to convert each item into an URL.  
        for( String token : tokens ) 
        {
            try
            {
                Url url = as("mycompany", "someapikey").call(shorten(token));
                Log.d("SHORTENED", token + " was shortened!");
                shortenedBody = body.replace(token, url.getShortUrl());
            }
            catch(BitlyException e)
            {
                //Log.d("BitlyException", token + " could not be shortened!");

            }
        }

        composeEditText.setText(shortenedBody);
        // url.getShortUrl() -> http://bit.ly/fB05
    }
```

After the links are shortened, I want to print the modified string in an EditText. My EditText is not displaying my messages properly.

For example:

```
"I like www.google.com" should be "I like [some shortened url]" after my code executes.
```

Comment: What gets printed to the EditText?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, strings are immutable. String.replace() returns a new string which is the result of the replacement. Thus, when you do `shortenedBody = body.replace(token, url.getShortUrl());` in a loop, `shortenedBody` will hold the result of (only the very) last replace.

Here's a fix, using StringBuilder.

```
public void shortenMessage()
{
    String body = composeEditText.getText().toString();
    StringBuilder shortenedBody = new StringBuilder();
    String [] tokens = body.split("\\s");

    // Attempt to convert each item into an URL.  
    for( String token : tokens ) 
    {
        try
        {
            Url url = as("mycompany", "someapikey").call(shorten(token));
            Log.d("SHORTENED", token + " was shortened!");
            shortenedBody.append(url.getShortUrl()).append(" ");
        }
        catch(BitlyException e)
        {
            //Log.d("BitlyException", token + " could not be shortened!");

        }
    }

    composeEditText.setText(shortenedBody.toString());
    // url.getShortUrl() -> http://bit.ly/fB05
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is great progress. The shortened URL gets displayed in the EditText but the rest of the string is not being printed. For example: "I like www.google.com" will print just the shortened URL. How can I print "I like [shortened url here]" ?

Answer (score -1):

You'll probably want [String.replaceAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [Pattern.quote](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) to "quote" your string before you pass it to replaceAll, which expects a regex.

Comment: irrelevant; no "replaceAll" in the question anywhere